# Calculating Grid Convergence

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, grids-graticules, bearing, convergence

When ESRI tool "Calculate Grid Convergence Angle (Cartography)" is used to calculate line bearing or azimuth, is the bearing referenced to True North or Grid North?

Comment: Thanks Mapperz. My question should have been when the bearing of a line is calculated using the "Add Geometry Attribute (LINE_BEARING)" tool, is the bearing referenced to Grid North or True North?

Answer (score 0):

Existing field that will be populated with the **true north calculation** value in decimal degrees.

Note:

rotation_method (optional)

- GEOGRAPHIC —Angle is calculated clockwise with 0 at top. This is the
  default.
- ARITHMETIC —Angle is calculated counterclockwise with 0 at    right.
- GRAPHIC —Angle is calculated counterclockwise with 0 at top.

Source:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/calculate-grid-convergence-angle.htm

Comment: Thanks Mapperz. My question should have been when the bearing of a line is calculated using the "Add Geometry Attribute (LINE_BEARING)" tool, is the bearing referenced to Grid North or True North?